# Paramater value '<' converted to '&lt;'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, urlencode

I am using ExpressJS with body-parser library.

When I pass a param value 2<5 then it is converted to `2&lt;5`

```
read: async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        let condition= req.query.condition|| req.body.condition  // condition= 2<5
```

Comment: What's wrong with that? That's the correct way to put a literal `<` in HTML.

Comment: What condition is reading in that case ? `req.query.condition` or `req.body.condition` ? Normally all query parameters are URL encoded by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reverse engineering in my code, I found that npm library xss creating the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Server is converting every < into &lt; in req.body. can you please help me with this. How you solve this problem.